# Embed Flash App to youtube

Tags: flash, youtube

I'm wondering how http://www.youtube.com/user/tippexperience this site works? Is it possible to embed the swf to youtube? I check developer guide on youtube but there isn't any guideline for that.

Does anyone know how this works?

Answer (score 0):

Almost anything can be done if you have enough money ;).

Kidding aside, that kind of thing is not something anyone can do, using an API YouTube provides or so. Instead, the company behind Tipp-Ex (I believe it is BIC) has no doubt payed a lot of money to YouTube for putting it up there. That is one way YouTube makes money, Vimeo has done similar things.

So unless you have a substantial budget for your project, I don't think you can do it.